# How can I use a single button click to achieve multiple actions in android eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to `Java` and `Android` development with Eclipse, so please pardon my "stupid" question (and my moniker).

I'm creating an app that takes in `user` `inputs`- weight and height, calculates the user's BMI (Body-Mass Index), `double bmi = weight/(height * height);` and displays the `output` in a `textView`. I've pretty much achieved that, but I'm stuck with the issues of how to:

Firstly, use a single `button` `click` to display the BMI value on one `textView1`;

Secondly, `display` some `text` on a different `textView2` depending on the range the user's BMI value falls into, using the `if` statement below:

```
if(bmi >= 0 && bmi < 22.01)
        {
            System.out.printf("Your BMI is " + "%1.2f", bmi);
            System.out.print(". That is too low, you are underweight.\nEat regularly and put on some weight.");
        }else if(bmi >= 22.01 && bmi < 25.01){
            System.out.printf("Your BMI is " + "%1.2f", bmi);
            System.out.print(". That is normal, maintain your healthy lifestyle.");
        }else if(bmi >= 25.01 && bmi < 30.01){
            System.out.printf("Your BMI is " + "%1.2f", bmi);
            System.out.print(". That is high, you are overweight!\nGet on a diet and exercise regularly.");
        }else if(bmi >= 30.01 && bmi < 40.01){
            System.out.printf("Your BMI is " + "%1.2f", bmi);
            System.out.print(". That is very high, you are OBESE!\nGet on a diet and exercise as often as you can.");
        }else{
            System.out.printf("Your BMI is " + "%1.2f", bmi);
            System.out.println("That is way too high, you are SEVERELY OBESE!\nGet on a diet asap and exercise everyday!");
        }
```

I've searched this site and others but couldn't sufficient help in this regard.
Thanks a bunch, in anticipation of your kind assistance!

Comment: Thanks @SaketMittal, checking it out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use 2 editText's for the input, and 2 TextView to display the BMI and to display the "Secendly":

in your main activity xml:

```
 <EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/Weight"
    android:hint="@string/Weight"
    android:inputType="number"/>

 <EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/Height"
    android:hint="@string/Height"
    android:inputType="number"/>

    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Height"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="BMI" />

    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/BMI"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/BMItext"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

and in your code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText Weight, Height;
private TextView BMI, BMItext;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BMItext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BMItext);        
    BMI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BMI);        
    Weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Weight);
    Height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Height);  
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Double Weightnum= Weight.getText().toString();
           Double WeightHeight = Weight.getText().toString()*Height.getText().toString();
            Double calculator = Weightnum/WeightHeight;
            BMI.setText("Your BMI is:" + calculator);
if(calculator >= 0 && calculator < 22.01)
    {
BMItext.settext("That is too low, you are underweight.\nEat regularly and put on some weight.");
                }else if(calculator >= 22.01 && calculator < 25.01){
        BMItext.settext("That is normal, maintain your healthy lifestyle.");
    }else if(calculator >= 25.01 && calculator < 30.01){
        BMItext.settext("That is high, you are overweight!\nGet on a diet and exercise regularly.");
    }else if(bmi >= 30.01 && bmi < 40.01){
        BMItext.settext("That is very high, you are OBESE!\nGet on a diet and exercise as often as you can.");
    }else{
        BMItext.settext("That is way too high, you are SEVERELY OBESE!\nGet on a diet asap and exercise everyday!");
    }

        }
    });

    }
 }
```

i hope i didnt miss anything, i created this code just here just now so.. :)

Comment: I haven't implemented this yet but I see the logic, looks like it will work (without the settext typos of course ;-)). I'll let you know the outcome as soon as I apply it, thanks a bunch.

Comment: I adapted my code using your logic and it worked a treat. Wish I could give you a vote up but I haven't the enough reputation yet. Thanks a million!

Comment: You can just click the V :)

Comment: Oh, ok done that. Sorry, still getting to know the ropes. Cheers! 

Answer (score 1):

How do you detect the click? With a onClickListener or with a onClick tag in the XML file?
Either way you will get a method in your activity, which will get executed when your button is clicked. Just put every code that is supposed to get executed in this method.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas, I'm detecting it with onClickListener, not with an onClick tag in XML file. I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: It worked fine. Adapted my code as suggested by @Didi78, and its smooth as I anticipated. Thanks for your assistance.